# Specify Network Interface in Docker Compose File

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I have multiple interfaces from my main server, e.g. (`eno1`, `eno2`, `eno3`, etc.) and multiple interfaces from an additional ethernet card, e.g. (`enp7s0f0`,  `enp7s0f1`, etc.). I want to set up all my `docker-compose.yaml` files to use the different interfaces, e.g. I want to have `service_1` use `eno2`, `service_2` to use `eno3`, and `service_3` use `enp7s0f0`. I want traffic in on specified ports and all traffic out to use the different interfaces.

Below is a sample `docker-compsoe.yaml`:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    service_1:
        build: .
        networks: 
            - eno2
        ports:
            - 7878:7878

networks:
   eno2:
      driver: macvlan
      driver_opts:
          parent: eno2
      ipam:
          driver: default
```

I'm not sure the proper format for specifying a different interface I've looked over the [Docker Compose Networking](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) page, but can't seem to find what I'm looking for. I need a solution that is fully contained in a `docker-compose.yaml` file.

Edit: The `macvlan` appears to be what I'm trying to configure. Following post from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61831255/how-to-create-a-docker-macvlan-with-user-defined-ip-and-mac-address-using-compos), I've edited Docker Compose file. However, I'm still not able to spin up multiple images that send outbound traffic through different interfaces, and activity goes through the default interface (`eno1`).

Comment: ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

The network interfaces are operating in the host's namespace, and unless you are using the `host` network, you will not be able to even see them in your containers, since docker will create interface for the container namespace.

You can restrict the traffic flow by making the container's port be binded only to a given IP address (that belongs to one of the network interfaces).

Assuming you want to use `enp7s0f0` for the service, and the interface has address `10.0.1.102` than you can specify the docker-compose as follows:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    service_1:
        build: .
        networks: 
            - eno1
        ports:
            - "10.0.1.102:7878:7878"

networks:
   eno1:
```

Comment: Does this affect outgoing traffic as well?

Comment: Not this one, the outgoing traffic will be affected by the routing table of the host. Once the host is set properly, the traffic will flow trough the interface you want. You can use `ip route` to check the routing tables

Comment: what if I want to bind to an interface that I don't have anything above physical layer enabled on?

Comment: You can not bind the physical adapter since binding happens on logical (socket) level. What you can do to have access to the physical interfaces is to use a "host" network in the container. In such case the applications in the container will have access to the network interfaces of the host. Depending on the use case, you might need to add entitlements (capabilities) to the container such as "NET_RAW"

Answer (score 0):

I found the docker-compose.yaml file able to recognize these options as I was working through the best way to uncover the root problem.

Here's the working `docker.compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    service_1:
        build: .
        networks: 
            - secure_web
        ports:
            - 7878:7878

networks:
   secure_web:
      driver: macvlan
      driver_opts:
          parent: eno1
      ipam:
          driver: default
```

You may want to additionally follow the following guides if you are looking for this solution:

- [Arch Linux Network Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration)
- [Hostname and /etc/hosts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186859/understand-hostname-and-etc-hosts)

Reading through those gave me a good refresher to tidy up exactly what I was looking for.